# How to upload my data to Minio after check the capacity of Minio

Tags: go, prometheus, minio

I want to upload many videos to my minio server ,but i think i should to check my minio's capacity
remaining first,i check the doc and the api witch minio provide but there is still no clue,also i try prometheus ,should i check the prometheus first?and run my code to delete data by my own?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prometheus/Grafana to check on total capacity and available capacity. You can use your own monitoring infrastructure or log into the MinIO Console via browser and click on "Monitoring". See https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/operations/monitoring/collect-minio-metrics-using-prometheus.html#cluster-metrics for reference.